# Present modal ViewController from SubView

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I am trying to present a modal view controller C from view controller B. B's view does not cover the full screen, and is a subview of another view controller, A. What I am seeing when I try to present a fullscreen modal is the modal is covering the full screen, but when I tap on certain places in the screen the control will get 'passed through' to A's view.

I can bypass this by presenting the modal from A via some kind of delegation, but I have no idea why this is happening! After all, if you have a tab bar controller managing one of your views, and you try to present a modal view, it covers the full screen just fine. Is there some magic going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is any official documentation on how the modal is implemented, but any view can get the [UIWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) of the [UIApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and call -presentModal... on the rootViewController property. This will have the affect of making your modal full screen. I'm sure there are other ways of achieving the same effect though.

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:myModalVC animated:YES];
```

In that scenario, you need to implement your own 'modal' methods for all your view controllers, using addSubview: and bringSubviewToFront:. I've done this in one of my larger project where I wanted some different behavior from the modal views.

Comment: this is in fact, what i did...it seems somewhat unsatisfactory though. for example, if you try to show a modal on a modal, then this technique does not work, as the second modal is now displayed below the first one.

Comment: yea, i have done exactly so by calling the root view controller. this seems to be still the best bang for buck.

Comment: I was having an issue with iOS 5 iPad's not displaying my presented view controllers and this was the fix I used, so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
UIViewController* vc = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UIWindow* keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView* topView = [[keyWindow subviews] objectAtIndex:[[keyWindow subviews] count] - 1];
vc.view = topView;

[vc presentModelViewController...
```

Basically, you create a new UIViewController and attach it to the topmost view on the main window (which is the view the user currently sees).

Comment: Messaging dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: on the modal view controller seems to no longer dismiss the view with your solution Elad... any thoughts ?

Comment: The same, with the new notation : 
    UIView *topView = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.subviews lastObject];

Answer (score 1):

Simple, but not sure about acceptance and efficiency. This is what I use.

1. Embed all the view controllers in a mainView below the rootView.
2. Add any modal views to the rootView while disabling userInteractionEnabled flag for the mainView. The modal view should be added to rootView and not mainView
3. Once done, re-enable the user interaction for mainView.

Hope this helps...